# Aggregate array of objects by specific key and sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, frontend

I have the following array filled with some objects:

```
const data = [
    {date: '8 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 20, 'b70 - plan1': 10, 'c30 - plan1': 5},
    {date: '9 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 60, 'b70 - plan1': 70, 'c30 - plan1': 20},
    {date: '8 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 10, 'b70 - plan1': 5, 'c30 - plan1': 5},
    {date: '9 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 5, 'b70 - plan1': 5, 'c30 - plan1': 5}
];
```

And I would like to group by the `date` and sum the fields that are equal resulting in the following array:

```
const data = [
    {date: '8 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 30, 'b70 - plan1': 15, 'c30 - plan1': 10},
    {date: '9 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 65, 'b70 - plan1': 75, 'c30 - plan1': 25},
];
```

I would be glad if I could get any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: You should have posted your attempt at it as well so we could have guided you where you have gone wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution can be separate into a hash map and then re-create a new array from it.

```js
const data = [
    {date: '8 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 20, 'b70 - plan1': 10, 'c30 - plan1': 5},
    {date: '9 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 60, 'b70 - plan1': 70, 'c30 - plan1': 20},
    {date: '8 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 10, 'b70 - plan1': 5, 'c30 - plan1': 5},
    {date: '9 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 5, 'b70 - plan1': 5, 'c30 - plan1': 5}
];

const groupDataByDate = (array) => {
    const groups = {};
    
  // we create a hash map with the sum of each element grouping by date
    array.forEach(item => {
    const { date, ...props }  = item;
    
    if (!groups[date]) groups[date] = {};
    
    Object.keys(props).forEach(key => {
            if (!groups[date][key]) groups[date][key] = 0;
      
      groups[date][key] += item[key];
    })
  });
  

    // if we want to preserve as an array, we need to transform this hash map into the same array
    return Object.keys(groups).map(key => {
    return {
        date: key,
      ...groups[key], // this attribute contains the sums for each group
    };
  });
  
  // otherwise you can just return the groups
  // uncomment next line if the object helps you
  // return groups;
}

console.log(groupDataByDate(data));
/*
// expected result
const data = [
    {date: '8 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 30, 'b70 - plan1': 15, 'c30 - plan1': 10},
    {date: '9 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 65, 'b70 - plan1': 75, 'c30 - plan1': 25},
];
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

using simple reduce can give you the solution.
first, use a dictionary to insert the first set of unique 'date' as key and object as value, and when you find another matching date key, simply add current with the previous value saved in the dictionary.

```js
const data = [
    {date: '8 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 20, 'b70 - plan1': 10, 'c30 - plan1': 5},
    {date: '9 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 60, 'b70 - plan1': 70, 'c30 - plan1': 20},
    {date: '8 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 10, 'b70 - plan1': 5, 'c30 - plan1': 5},
    {date: '9 - 2021', 'a20 - plan1': 5, 'b70 - plan1': 5, 'c30 - plan1': 5}
];

let dictionary = data.reduce((dic, value)=> { 
if(!dic[value.date])
{dic[value.date] = value; } else { 
    let old =  dic[value.date];
   Object.keys(old).forEach((key)=> { if(key != 'date') {   old[key] += value[key] } } ) 
  }      return dic } ,{});

let result = Object.values(dictionary);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help vaira. Yeah I should have posted my attempt but It wasn't getting me anywhere, I was desperate to solve this thing.